# Win32_MountPoint alternative for xp

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, c#-4.0, wmi

Is there any alternative for Win32_MountPoint WMI class that is available on xp?

Comment: possible duplicate of [availability of Win32_MountPoint and Win32_Volume on Windows XP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815296/availability-of-win32-mountpoint-and-win32-volume-on-windows-xp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're actually aware of the fact, that `Win32_MointPoint` is just an association class between `Win32_Volume` (which consequently is also not available on Windows XP) and `Win32_Directory`. So a more valid question would actually be "is there an alternative for getting the volume of a directory?".

You could probably achieve the same using the `Win32_LogicalDiskRootDirectory` association with a `Win32_Directory` instance, looking up the `Win32_LogicalDisk` instance that a directory is located on.

`Win32_LogicalDisk` does not provide all the information that `Win32_Volume` does (for example `DirtyBitSet`), but most of it.

You might consider changing your question to state what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I wish to catch its instance creation event (theoretically should fire when new mounted folder is created, not sure ),but I can't do that in xp. Is there a workaround. Win32_Volume also isn't available on xp.

Comment: Can't you just subscribe to the instance creation event of `Win32_LogicalDisk` instead? Even though not exactly the same, they do refer to the same basic concept of a logical disk, partition or volume.

Comment: Yes , but this only works if disk is to shown in My Computer, but I have an situation when disk is mounted to folder ,but not shown in My Computer.

Comment: Actually, there is related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2815296/21567) on SO already. You might want to check it out. Looks like you need to use P/Invoke on the [native volume management functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365730%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).